# cant detect WIFI usb adapter(Kali linux Vm)

Tags: networking, kali-linux, usb, virtualbox

I am using:

1.kali linux 2020 latest version.
2.TP-LINK TL-WN821N.
3.Oracle VM with extentions.

I configured the usb in vm USB->USB2->Realtek
and in filters I added "Remote:Yes"

in the termial "lsusb" I see that my adapter is connected but when I use "airmon-ng" I cant see my usb.

edit: this adapter and everything working well in my fedora linux(not on VM).

Answer (score 0):

There is a VM distro of kali which I think has all the required drivers .  But if you want to manually install the drivers [TP-Link Driver page](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/) There is installation guide (with Kali included)